# How to check that a p-datatable has been rendered?

Tags: angular, primeng-datatable

Let say I have a parent and child components.

```
<button (click)="downloadReport()">Download Report</button>

<app-child-component [reportMode]="reportMode" (onReportModeReady)="onReportModeReady">
</app-child-component>
```

On the child component I need to hide/display some PrimeNg Component

```
<p-datatable #dtNormal ngIf="!reportMode"></p-datatable> //normal data table

<p-datatable#dtReport ngIf="reportMode"></p-datatable> //strip out version for report.
```

The problem I'm having is that the report is being built before even the normal is hidden and the report table is display.

I'd like to build the report only after the the report table is visible so that the child component can fire an event telling to the parent that's everything is ready.

How do I know that **Report primeNG datable** is ready?

Thanks

Comment: Would you please consider replicating this with a Sample [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular)? It would be helpful in having a look at.

Comment: @SiddAjmera Stackblitz???

Comment: What do you mean by "ready"? do you mean rendered?

Comment: @Calidus: yes. I mean when the p-dataTable has been rendered. After the p-DataTable has been rendered on the child component, I'd like to notify the parent component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could search the dom for the element `document.getElementById("dtReport");` during each `ngAfterViewChecked` until it is found. Then emit the event the first time you find it.

https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Instead of using ngIf you could toggle the visibility which would be much faster because #dtReport would get created in the dom when the component is created instead of being to create it when reportModel changes.

fyi p-datatable is deprecated, it has been replaced with p-table

Comment: thanks so much. I'll spend more time exploring the rest on the life cycle hooks. Also, to respond to why I'm still using `p-dataTable` is because we inherited the project from another team. We'll be upgrading the solution after the next release. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a need to know when large images were rendered and used:

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(x => {
    // its loaded here.
});
```

You will have to find something to hook into to call the above before you try to load it, etc.  Perhaps put it into its own component.